# Attribute disappears in asp .net TextBox

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

I have the following asp .net markup:

```
<asp:TextBox CssClass="siteinput required" ID="TextTitle" runat="server" Width="100%" MaxLength='<%# int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]) == 49 ? 40 : 15 %>' placeholder="Title" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
```

but the generated markup is:

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$TextTitle" type="text" id="MainContent_TextTitle" class="siteinput required" placeholder="Title" required="required" style="width:100%;" />
```

The MaxLength attribute disappears strangely, any idea?

Comment: Have you tried `Convert.ToInt32()` instead of `int.Parse() / Int32.Parse()`. May be your id is not a valid integer

Comment: It is valid integer this is not the problem for sure

Answer (score 2):

```
<%# ...
```

is databinding tag

try as below if you're not binding anything and doing some calculations.

```
 <%= ...
```

EDIT:

```
public int MaxLengthById
{
    get

    {
       //Check the QueryString before parse
        return int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]) == 49 ? 40 : 15;

    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //option 1  
   TextTitle.MaxLength = MaxLengthById;

   //option 2 
   TextTitle.DataBind();

}
```

Markup side;

**Option 1** 
Remove MaxLength attribute completely. It will be added on page load.

```
<asp:TextBox CssClass="siteinput required" ID="TextTitle" runat="server" Width="100%" placeholder="Title" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Option 2**
Bind your property with the variable name

```
<asp:TextBox CssClass="siteinput required" ID="TextTitle" runat="server" Width="100%" MaxLength=<%# MaxLengthById %>  placeholder="Title" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I need to change the value depending on the query string, and replacing #  with = did not solve it

Comment: oh ok, that was a server side element. sorry. 

there are two options here; set the value on server side on page load etc or place html input element if you set just one attribute in calculations.

Comment: I know that it can be set in behind code and this was what I did really but my question was that if it can be done without any usage of code behind

Comment: Anyway thank you for your information, your effort is appreciated